# Meteor collection differs on server and client

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a collection called GameMaps, defined like this:

```
GameMaps = new Meteor.Collection('gameMaps');
```

An entry in this collection looks like this:

```
{
  name: 'foo',
  structure: {
    arg1: 'bar',
    fields: [
      {name: 'someName', value: 'someValue'},
      {name: 'someOtherName', value: 'someOtherValue'}
    ]
  }
}
```

Now on the server I can access the first field of the structure in the following way:

```
GameMaps.findOne({name: 'foo'}).structure.fields[0]
```

which returns this object as expected:

```
{name: 'someName', value: 'someValue'}
```

But when I try to execute the same on the client I get an empty object:

```
Object {}
```

My publication for the collection looks like this:

```
Meteor.publish('allMaps', function() {
  return GameMaps.find();
});
```

And the subscription like this:

```
Meteor.subscribe('allMaps');
```

On the client I see everything of this collections item except for the objects in the "fields" array. I even see the amount of items in the "fields" Array but can not access them. I guess I am missing something when publishing the collection, but I don't see what.

Comment: What happens if you change the name `fields` to something else?

Comment: Can you also show the code for the definition of the collection? Also, is there a reason why you put the subscribe command into an autorun block?

Comment: How are you accessing these? Do you wait for the subscription to finish? Does it do the same if you try to access it in your js console?

Comment: @ChristianF I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @Akshat yes, the subscription finishes. I can access all other parts of the collection via js console, just not the objects in the fields array.

Comment: @DavidWeldon hmmm, can you explain why the name of the attribute should make any difference?

Comment: It's a reserved word used for [field specifiers](http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers). If changing it fixes the problem, then its probably a bug. I just didn't have time to check it myself.

Comment: I tested this type of collection to see if I can reproduce the issue but I can't. Do you have any other publish functions? What happens if you add back `meteor add autopublish`?

Comment: @DavidWeldon tested it with the same document above seems to work fine. Also works ok if `fields` is one level higher. I also thought it might be reserved since its part of the ddp `added` message.

Comment: I also was unable to reproduce the issue ([my code](https://gist.github.com/dwinston/7865309)).

Comment: Upon further investigation I found out, that the JSON I am importing the fields from, in some cases also has a field called length, so my example from above works as expected, just not when this additional `length` field is there.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you identified in your comments, your issue is that you have a field named "length" . Unfortunately the serialisation code mistakes the object as an array if it has a `length` property.

See [bug report](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/594?source=c).

A hacky workaround is to rename the field to something else like `safeLength`, `overrideLength`, `len` or even `langth` .